# A tag getting click instead of touchstart

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, zepto

I am using `touchstart` event instead of `click` when available.

But whenever I have a link `<a href..` and I press on it on my mobile phone, it takes 300ms to fire. Is there a way to make it work as if it was bound to the `touchstart` event instead of `click`?

Comment: Native JS or jQuery implemntation?

Comment: jQuery (I'm using zepto)

Comment: Zepto is similar to jQuery, but it's not the same thing AFAICT.

Comment: It's okay I can adapt the answer..